# Why can't switch from PHP5.6 to 7.2

Tags: php

I'm migrating from PHP5.6 to 7.2 on Debian 9, my applications work correctly in the previous version, but when I disable the PHP5.6 module in Apache and enable 7.2, it starts to show the code, if I run in a page the phpinfo () function is displaying it correctly.

PHPinfo:

[image]

Comment: I think you should reinstall apache, because I remember that you have to choose PHP version you are installing apache for - perhaps it creates different configs.

Comment: Did you ***restart*** apache? You don't need to reinstall apache.

Comment: I do, when switch the apache modules, i restart the apache server.

Comment: *Very* wild guess: is your code using short open tags (i.e. `<?` instead of `<?php`)? These may be disabled in your new settings file.

Comment: uninstall all instances of php 5?